# How to get Tear Down This Tower achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii

This is the one where you let Siegebreaker destroy 6 towers near the demon gate in Act 3. But where exactly is this gate? I tried letting him destroy the towers in the arena where you fight him, but it didn't do anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely there's a bug with this. You are indeed in the right arena. [Some have suggested](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5270828327) sticking close to the siegebreaker, and dismissing your follower. Be sure to not accidently topple them yourself, too.